# From a Userform when a _change sub is run setting focus in the spreadsheet to the cell you are modifying

Tags: excel, vba

```
   Private Sub CmbBoxRETFileReceived_change()
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Set rng1 = Sheets("MAIN").Range("B:B").Find(CStr(TxtBoxFUZEProjectID.Value), [B100000], 
xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlNext)
   If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
   Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "U") = CmbBoxRETFileReceived.Text
   'ActiveCell = (Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "U"))
   Else
   End If
   End Sub
```

I have a spreadsheet with columns all the way to BG and a user form to modify them but no matter what I have tried I can't get the spreadsheet to "focus" on the cell being modified.
I tried below but it fails
'ActiveCell = (Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "U"))

Comment: You'd want `Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row,"U").Activate`

Answer (score 1):

### Select a Cell Using `Application.GoTo`

- To select a cell, you have to make sure that its sheet is visible (not covered here) and selected. To activate a sheet, you have to make sure that its workbook is active. To select a sheet, you have to additionally make sure its workbook is visible (not covered here).
- You can use `Application.GoTo` which will activate the cell's workbook, select the cell's worksheet, and select the cell.

```vb
Private Sub CmbBoxRETFileReceived_Change()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Main")
    
    Dim scell As Range, dcell As Range
    
    With ws.Columns("B")
        Set scell = .Find(CStr(TxtBoxFUZEProjectID.Value), _
            .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlPart)
    End With
       
    If Not scell Is Nothing Then
        Set dcell = scell.EntireRow.Columns("U")
        dcell.Value = CmbBoxRETFileReceived.Text
        Application.Goto dcell, False ' True to scroll to; try it
    'Else
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why check if the workbook is active already or not, afaik there's no performance issue when it already is active, or is that a coding habbit?

Comment: An all in one solution, aha! :D

Comment: @Notus_Panda I've modified my answer. I didn't realize that `Application.GoTo` also activates the correct workbook. About the issue you've mentioned (*"just use `wb.Activate`"*), I've occasionally been doing the same with `.ScreenUpdating`, `.EnableEvents`, `.AutoFilterMode`... as you said, as if there is a performance issue. I guess I'll have to stop doing it. Thanks for pointing it out. Believe it or not, I was just thinking about this issue the other day (Habits die hard.).

Comment: I heard people talking about something similar earlier: At the start you learn the basics, then you learn certain rules and habits but the more advanced you get, the more you need to unlearn (bad) beginner habits. Luckily for you, these ones don't hurt anything ^^